# Crypt generating *0

Tags: php, passwords

Crypt is, sometimes, generating the string `*0` instead of a real hash.

```
const SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
const HASH_PAYLOAD = 13;
public static function createHash($password, $cost = self::HASH_PAYLOAD) {

    $salt = '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(self::SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)); 

    $password = crypt($password, $salt);
    return $password;
}
```

I found the line `base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(self::SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));` somewhere around Stackoverflow, stating it is a good way to generate a Random salt. Its been a few weeks so i couldn't find that answer again. I wonder if that random salt maybe is causing crypt to generate the string `*0`.

The given password is always a alphanumeric string, 8 chars long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crypt` returns `*0` also if given an invalid salt - and that's the case here. Quoting [**the doc**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

> Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: `"$2a$"`, `"$2x$"` or `"$2y$"`, a
>   two digit cost parameter, `"$"`, and 22 characters from the alphabet
>   **`"./0-9A-Za-z"`**

Most probably, you've assumed that `base64_encode()` returns strings of the same set of characters. But it's not - there's also a `+` sign (the full alphabet is `[a-zA-Z0-9+/]`).

An obvious workaround is just replacing all `+` with `.`:

```
$salt = '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . 
  str_replace('+', '.', 
    base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(self::SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)));
```